# How to create an API Gateway for AWS Eks services in private subnets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS EKS cluster running in a custom VPC with 2 public and 2 private subnets. The node groups (for my backend) run in the 2 private subnets so they can't be accessed directly.

I would like to create an API Gateway which exposes the microservices in the node group so my front-end and third party software can communicate with them. I eventually also like to add authorization to the API Gateway for secutiry. The problem is that I cannot find a good documentation how to do this (Expose the microservices through an API Gateway). Does anyone now khow to do this or where I can find information on how to do this?

The situation would look something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use API Gateway private integrations to expose services running in EKS using NLB. Please check the below article  for overall solution .

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/integrate-amazon-api-gateway-with-amazon-eks/

Comment: Thank you for answering. I eventually ended up using ingress nginx which creates a classic load balencer. I am now able to use this load balancer as my backend endpoint.